# Wordpress Theme cannot find CSS (localhost)

Tags: css, html, wordpress-theming, bitnami

I am using the Wordpress theme from http://html5blank.com, and it works great when I upload it to my servers online, but when I use it locally using a Wordpress Bitnami Stack the theme cannot find the css. In *header.php* you have:

```
<!-- css + javascript -->
<?php wp_head(); ?>
```

but when I view the source of dev site at localhost (after activating the theme) I find the `href` of the css is empty:

```
<!-- css + javascript -->
<link rel='stylesheet' id='normalize-css'  href='' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='html5blank-css'  href='' media='all' />
```

Meanwhile it does find the images and icons:

```
<!-- icons -->
<link href="http://localhost:8080/wordpress/wp-content/themes/html5blank-master/img/icons/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon">
<link href="http://localhost:8080/wordpress/wp-content/themes/html5blank-master/img/icons/touch.png" rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed">
```

My OS is Ubuntu 12.10. Could this be Bitnami issue, or is this something I could fix so I can work on the website locally? Note that default theme "twentytwelve" works fine in my setup.

**UPDATE:** I compared and tried both versions 1.2.9 and 1.4.0 (current version) of *html5blank* theme in my Bitnami Wordpress stack. The `functions.php` files of both versions are identical as far as the `wp_register_style()` is concerned, yet version 1.2.9 fills in the links to the css while version 1.4.0 leaves the them empty. Also note that 1.4.0 works perfectly fine in Bitnami install on Windows 7.

Comment: I've just tried it (I was planning on giving it a try anyway!) and it works for me locally, under a non-Bitnami install. There doesn't seem to be anything odd about the way the styles are queued (it's done in the function `html5blank_styles`, starting at line 130 in `functions.php`, if that's any help.) Is there anything in Bitnami's  apache error logs?

Comment: No, nothing I can find in Bitnami's apache logs. I even restarted the services and it gives the same results. I tried adding the stylesheets myself to the `header.php` file and the css works perfect that way, but the `functions.php` method flops every time and leaves the link empty.

Comment: Re: your update, are you running the same version of WordPress locally and on the server? I'm wondering if it's something odd like an interaction between a WordPress bug and the exact way the theme is coded, or something...

Comment: Well, here's something: I can reproduce your issue, using Bitnami on OS X. Exactly the same.

Comment: Yes, both are running wordpress 3.5.1, the latest and greatest. I have no idea what kind of a bug this is or which piece of software is responsible, but if someone else could re-create it we might find out a little more.

Comment: So maybe a bug with interactions between that version of the theme and Bitnami for linux and OSX? Weird...

Comment: I've traced it to esc_url() returning empty when run over the href url in the WP_Styles class. Not sure why it's doing it yet. It *may* be being confused by the port number -- is your BitNami install running on a non-standard port? (Mine's running on 8080 by default, so my site URL looks like `http://localhost:8080/wordpress/`.)

Comment: Windows uses `http://127.0.0.1/wordpress` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is an interaction between some code in the theme design and WordPress running on a non-standard port number.

I tracked things down to the function `wp_kses_bad_protocol` reporting to WordPress's `esc_url` function (which is used by the style enqueuer, the `WP_Styles` class in `wp-includes/class.wp-styles.php`) that the protocol for the stylesheet URL was invalid. `esc_url` is there to prevent naughty things making it into URLs; one of the checks is to see if there's anything suspicious like the `javascript:` protocol instead of `http:`, for example.

The false detection of a problem seems to have been caused by the html5blank theme adding a filter function `html5blank_protocol_relative` for the filter `style_loader_src`. This doesn't seem like a bad thing to do, in general ([protocol relative](http://paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/) basically means replacing `http://whatever...` with `//whatever...`, which avoids problems mixing https and http on the same page -- the "protocol relative" URL of `//whatever` will use https or http as appropriate.)

However, when you're running WordPress on a particular port number, that seems to confuse the bad protocol detection.

Long story short: you may want to report this to the developer of the theme, to let him know that because of this, his theme breaks when running WordPress on a non-standard port, i.e. with a URL like `http://localhost:8080/wordpress`, rather than `http://localhost/wordpress`.

In the short term, I'd just comment out these lines:

```
add_filter('script_loader_src', 'html5blank_protocol_relative'); // Protocol relative URLs for enqueued scripts
add_filter('style_loader_src' , 'html5blank_protocol_relative'); // Protocol relative URLs for enqueued styles
```

...in the theme's `functions.php`; that should turn off the protocol relative URL filtering, and your theme should work locally. Unless your live sites use https, they should still work just fine with this change, too, and even if they do use https, you won't be any worse off than with most themes that are out there.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to look at functions.php - your theme is likely using enque as a method to pass the CSS to the wp_head. See this tutorial for more info: http://wp.tutsplus.com/articles/how-to-include-javascript-and-css-in-your-wordpress-themes-and-plugins/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. From checking out that tutorial it seems like this _functions.php_ (which I have not modified from what you get at [html5blank.com](http://html5blank.com)) is properly set up, but it's just not spitting out the full code when viewing at _localhost_. It's weird that only the links to the css files are affected...

Comment: Enquing is the proper way to do it, but you can also call it manually like: <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo( 'template_directory' ); ?>/style.css"> I wouldn't recommend it normally, but it would be a shame for something so small to keep you from doing more important work.

Comment: You are right, seems trivial to let this get in my way, but I thought I might be able to find a fix through this channel. The manual fix does work fine, and then I might assume that I can remove the work-around once I upload it to my servers as the `functions.php` method seems to work everywhere except my Ubuntu Bitnami Wordpress stack. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the Divi theme from Elegant Themes, you might encounter the same issue where the results of your design work don't reflect the settings you made in the visual builder. To solve this issue on localhost, you simply have to install the WP File Manager plugin, go to wp-content and delete the et-cache folder. THAT'S IT!